# Как через SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS получить индекс на элементы коллекции, которые вызвали исключения?

Tags: oracle, исключения, plsql

Я взял этот код в качестве примера из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885531):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE) IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
     ---trying to rasie an exception by using a calculation
    SET SALARY=SALARY * 999999999999
    WHERE ID_E= V_EMP_ID(INDX);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
        ---I'm printing the value of the exception array.
        dbms_output.put_line('exception Raised for record' ||V_EMP_ID(i));           
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Объясните, как `V_EMP_ID(i)` может указывать на элемент, который вызвал исключение?

Так как `i` берётся из `1 ... SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT`', то при одной ошибке `V_EMP_ID(i)` всегда будет указывать на первый элемент коллекции.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How does FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT point to the elements of the collection that threw the exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65329539) от участника [@AnuC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13518431/anuc)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65329539

Answer (score 3):

Принятый ответ не значит, что он полность верный.

Из оф. документации кап. [12.4.1.4 Handling FORALL Exceptions After FORALL Statement Completes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-DAF46F06-EF3F-4B1A-A518-5238B80C69FA):

> SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX is the number of the DML statement that failed.

Порядковый номер DML это тоже самое, что индекс на элемент коллекции в `FORALL`.

Попробуйте следующий простой рабочий пример:

```sql
create table tab (id, val check (val<=3)) as
    select rownum, rownum from dual connect by level<=3
/
declare 
    type idtab is table of int;
    ids idtab;
begin    
    select id bulk collect into ids
    from tab;
    
    declare
        forallexcp exception;
        pragma exception_init (forallexcp, -24381);
    begin
        forall i in 1..ids.count save exceptions
            update tab set val = val + 1
            where id = ids(i); 
    exception when forallexcp then
        dbms_output.put_line (
            sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted ('||sql%bulk_exceptions.count||' with error).');
        for i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop dbms_output.put_line (
            'id='||ids(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index)||' sqlerrm='||
            sqlerrm (-(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code)));
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
2 row(s) inserted (1 with error).
id=3 sqlerrm=ORA-02290: check constraint (.) violated
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331361) от участника [0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>